# Is it thread-safe to set value to class member property in CompletableFuture callback?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, thread-safety, completable-future

I am new to `CompletableFuture` in Java 8 and I wonder whether the following code snippet is thread-safe when I set the result to class member properties in a callback, and try to read them after the `allOf().get()` call, and why?

```
public void newInit() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    CompletableFuture cf1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        return 1L;
    }).thenAccept(result -> {
        this.result1 = result;
    });
    CompletableFuture cf2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        return 2L;
    }).thenAccept(result -> {
        this.result2 = result;
    });
    CompletableFuture.allOf(cf1, cf2).get();
}
```

Comment: @DidierL I will read the values after CompletableFuture.allOf method, is it thread-safe?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is covered by the [Memory Consistency Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) defined on the `java.util.concurrent` package:

> [Chapter 17 of the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) defines the
>   *happens-before* relation on memory operations such as reads and writes of shared variables. **The results of a write by one thread are
>   guaranteed to be visible to a read by another thread only if the write
>   operation *happens-before* the read operation.** […]
>
> The methods of all classes in `java.util.concurrent` and its
>   subpackages extend these guarantees to higher-level synchronization.
>   In particular:
>
> - […]
> - Actions taken by the asynchronous computation represented by a `Future` *happen-before* actions subsequent to the retrieval of the
>     result via `Future.get()` in another thread.
> - […]

So to summarize, your `get()` call guarantees that your writes will be visible to the thread after it performs it.